# Can it be dangerous to use not popular(unknown) dns servers?

Tags: privacy, dns

There is a service called [tunlr](https://tunlr.com/), which let's you browse the web with no restrictions(Pandora, Hulu etc.). You just have to use their dns server.

But now I'm concerned whether the owners of the dns server could track usernames and passwords? Or are there even some other threats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A major concern would be that if you requested a legitimate domain, such as Google.com, they could direct you to a non-Google owned IP address. This would not be the site you were hoping to visit and there are major security concerns there. For example, the third-party website could be used to deliver malware. It might not be noticeable to you either. A common payload attack would deliver the legitimate website and embed a malicious iframe on the site. It's generally safest to use a known and trusted DNS provider.

See DNS Hijacking for more information:
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/stop-dns-hijacking/

Comment: If they could direct me to a third-party website, will I see a different domain then google.com in the adress bar? Or can they even fake the adress in the adress bar?

Comment: Because you are relying on their domain name resolution, your machine trusts the server. For example, if you request yahoo.com, they can direct you to a Google IP. The DNS service essentially works to translate IPs to easily readable addresses. DNS hijacking will change the DNS entries for a specific domain to point to a different IP address.

Comment: Ok, I got it thanks! Is there any way I can check if I am on the "real" site?

Comment: The best way I can think of checking is by performing an nslookup of the domain from the command line. This will have the computer resolve the domain via the DNS server. This will return an IP address or a series of IP addresses. After that, need to perform a third-party lookup of the IP (Such as Domain Tools' public Whois: http://whois.domaintools.com/) to verify that the returned IP has been associated with that domain. This isn't a 100% effective plan, but it will help to determine your risk. As I said before, the safest solution is use a trusted DNS provider.